# Find the minimize maximum weights in weighted graph using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, path, dynamic-programming, dijkstra, bellman-ford

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds the path from two vertices say ***s*** to ***t***, in a graph that has exactly ***k*** edges if paths exist.

And if multiple paths were found, the one with the minimum maximum weights of a single edge is preferred. (not the overall weights).

eg:   say K = 5

> Path 1: s - a - b - c - d - t with weights  1 - 1 - 1 - 10 - 1

the maximum weight of path 1 is 10

> Path 2: s - x - y - z - w - t with weights 7 - 9 - 8 - 6 - 7

the maximum weight of path 2 is 9, so this is preferred.

How exactly do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a modified version of the [Floyd-Warshal algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) that only iterates for K steps and forces the path lengths (by removing the `min` part)